# Trigger to update fields / unexpected token

Tags: trigger

I have just written a trigger, and I get an error "Unexpected token ; on line 2" . I really cannot understand why, and I have been looking at the code for hours now and cannot see what's wrong. Can anyone help? Tia.

```
trigger updateRenewals on Policy__c(before insert, before update) { 
List<ID> oppIDs = new List<ID>();

for (Policy__c pol: trigger.new){
    oppIDs.add(pol.Opportunity);
}

List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT ID, Inception_Date__c FROM Opportunity WHERE IS in: oppIDs]);


    for(integer i = 0; i < oppIDs.size();i++){
        if(pol.Opportunity == opps[i].id){
            opps[i].Inception_Date__c = Start_Date__c;
        }
    }
          update opps;
}
```

Comment: First thing I spot is you haven't opened the square bracket on the opps list line.

Comment: You need `()` before the `;` on line 2. See e.g. [Lists](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm).

Comment: So, what I am trying to do here is to assign the value of `Start_Date__c` on `Policy__c` to `Inception_Date__c` on `Opportunity`. The fields are all named correctly, and now I am getting an error: `variable does not exist: Start_Date__c`. Can anyone spot why?

Comment: Start_Date__c isn't defined in your trigger.  What object is Start_Date__c on?  Do you mean pol.Start_Date__c ?

Comment: @Lily you have edited your question so now the code you have doesn't match the error you say you are having on line 2. If you have a new problem you should create a new question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Jagular - Yes, and I tried `pol.Start_Date__c`, but it doesn't work either. I get the same error message.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Update Opportunities (and which ones) when a Policy is inserted or updated.  State the business problem clearly. Normally, updating related records is done in an after trigger